# a doubt on functor in Dummit&Foote's Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory, ring-theory, category-theory

The exercise3 on page915 in D&F's Abstract Algebra states that:

> Show that the map $\mathsf{Ring}$ to $\mathsf{Grp}$ by mapping a ring to its group of units (i.e., $R\mapsto R^{\times}$) defines a functor.

But for a non-trivial ring $R$ without $1$ , how to define $R^{\times}\in\mathsf{Grp}$ , I think it is an empty set and so, can it be in $\mathsf{Grp}$ ?

Furthermore, if $R=0$ is the zero ring, is it true that $R^\times\cong\{0\}$ where $\{0\}$ is the identity group?

Comment: They define $R^\times$ only if the ring has a unit $1\neq 0$. Moreover they define $\mathbf{Ring}$ to be the category of rings with unit and morphisms need to map units to units (page 912)

Comment: @Jonas Thanks, I was reviewing this chapter so I had forgotten the initial definition of $\mathbf[Ring}$ .

Comment: That's an answer, @Jonas, not a comment!

Answer (score 1):

On page 912 the category $\mathbf{Ring}$ is defined to be the category of unital rings (=rings with a unit) with unital morphisms (mapping units to units).

On page 226 the group $R^\times$ is defined for rings with unit $1 \neq 0$.

I would assume that for the zero ring, one would define $R^\times$ to be the trivial group.

Comment: Yes, Example(1) states that $R=0$ is the only ring where $1=0$ on page 224, I just found.